# Business Case for abandoning IE7 as the *developer's* browser?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm a software developer.  The only browser I have at work is IE7.  I don't have freedom to select my browser.

I am *constantly* learning and researching things online and, of course, IE7 is a *very* poor tool for doing that work.

I've been invited to present a business case for replacing the dev team's IE7 browsers w/ a something more modern.  **I don't want browser recommendations**, and this isn't about which browser the users of my *software/webapps* will use, but...

... what behaviors/traits/sideeffects of IE7 should I highlight when making the case that it has a very real negative impact when I'm trying to do my work as a software developer?

Do I talk about security vulnerabilities (on my workstation)?  Do I talk about the cost of waiting for tabs to open all day?  Do I talk about the memory leaks?  Do I try to measure how often the browser just flat-out crashes on me?  What would resonate best with the corporate decision makers?

Comment: Are you a web developer?

Comment: A good start would be to tell us why you feel IE7 "is a _very_ poor tool for [learning and researching things online]".  What type of developer are you?  A web developer could benefit from FF and Firebug or the developer tools in IE8, e.g.  What operating system are you using?  How good is your computer?  Maybe the problem is your system and not the browser - trying wiping it and reinstalling everything and see if that helps (our company uses IE7 and I'm a developer and I have none of your problems).  Do your coworkers have these problems?

Comment: Really, though, this is a poor question.  In essence you've said, "I don't want to hear your opinions; I just want you to make a case to my bosses so I can get my way."

Comment: I know this sounds like I'm being difficult, but it's not that.  I can't pave my box (myriad reasons why, and I know that restricts our role as solution providers to this question).  More comments coming.

Comment: We have two workstations in our cubicles.  The first is a Windows 7 box w/ Fx (great browsing experience; very effective as a streamlined, speedy learning tool).  Our Internet access on that box has just been revoked permanently.  The second is an XP box w/ IE7, which has (slow, but that's unimproveable and outside this question's scope) Internet access.

Comment: I'm develop web apps, but also WPF.  I'm thinking it's less relevant what kind of apps I write given that the workstation whose browser I'm talking about isn't the workstation on which I do my development.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Why is IE7 a poor "learning tool"?  Are you taking an interactive class with streaming video or just reading websites?  The computer I'm on now at work (XP with IE7) is not my development machine and it's great - rock solid, fast, no crashes.  Was your second computer removed from the network for security reasons or as punishment?  You still haven't said why it's bad, how you know it's the browser and not the machine, and if all your coworkers have this problem.

Comment: Mea culpa.  IE7 renders several sites poorly (I'm talking about blemishes that go beyond cosmetic -- when I look at your SO profile page, the page's gray footer DIV renders right on top of your "Returning an error and message from a Spring controller or service" question in the list of your questions).  Three seconds pass between Ctrl-T being pressed and the new tab being prepared to accept URL input.  I middle-click on links to see a new tab open, but the new tab never even attempts to load the page -- the address bar never gets populated w/ the URL.  I can list more if it's necessary.

Comment: For the sake of discussion, I can offer this: if the "poor" comes from addons/etc that have nothing to do w/ IE7 (I have no control over which addons are loaded by the browser), these addons wouldn't be part of the experience w/ a new browser, and the decision makers aren't going to be able to differentiate between IE7 and its addons when seeking scapegoats for a "poor learning tool" experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words that important people like to hear:

- Security (use open security vulnerability charts and such)
- Standards (talk *very briefly* about web standards, but then hammer in the point that IE does not follow them throughout the presentation)
- Productivity (here's where you get to talk about speed, additional features etc)

Also make sure to talk about the minimal cost that the switch will have in terms of IT time required.

Comment: The switch actually is very expensive.  This is happening on a global network whose changes are *buried* under paperwork and red tape.  All three of your bullet points are helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You did not explain what you are developing, and who you do it for. If you develop for an audience of 15,000 IE7 users, I think you have a weak case.

If you develop public websites, you have a very strong case, and many arguments to support it. It all depends ....

Comment: Not really an answer...more of a comment on the question.

Comment: Surely, though, using IE7 would be reasonable when testing the apps that *I* write (for IE7 users) and fairly irrelevant when using the browser purely as a *learning tool*, which isn't rendering the app *I've* created (again, the apps I create sometimes aren't even *web* apps, but I still need to research and *learn* things all day long).